# file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\instant\storage\framework/sessions/FF): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was trying to upload this instance on Amazon elasticBeanstalk, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried using ssh to access the files to no avail.

i did `php artisan config:cache` and `composer dump-autoload` before uploading.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: meant file not ile

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to directory ***laravel/bootstrap/cache*** and delete `config.php` file.

Answer (score 4):

Open terminal in your project directory and run this cmd:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

How did I solve this issue? After running those commands and not getting the solution.

```
composer dump-autoload
composer install
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
php artisan clear-compiled
```

The issue was simple. In my case under `storage/framework` there is `sessions` folder is missing so I created the directory and run the command again. And issue solved.

**Note: In some cases if your run `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`. Your issue will be solved.

Hope this thread will solve your issue.
Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

run `php artisan vendor:publish`
Asking Which provider or tag's files would you like to publish?:
Type 0
Then run `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

Can try using `php artisan optimize`. This will clear everything that cache your projects.

Let me know if this help you guys. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This command work in my case: `php artisan config: clear`

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33568542)

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me when i changed all paths in C:\xampp\htdocs...\bootstrap\cache\config.php