# Laravel 8 delete bootstrap/cache/config file

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I uploaded my ***localhost project*** on ***Godaddy Shared hosting***.

After uploading my project i got this error

`file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\instant\storage\framework/sessions/FF): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

to remove this error i followed this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59595863/file-put-contentsc-xampp-htdocs-instant-storage-framework-sessions-ff-failed) and deleted my **bootstrap/cache/config.php**

I have two questions -

1. will there be any effect on performance if i
   delete **bootstrap/cache/config.php**?
2. can i create this new file by `php artisan` command?

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on the size of your configurations, but in most cases the performance impact would be marginal.
2. `php artisan config:cache`